# Function for multiplication of 2 polynomials defined as structure

Tags: structure, multiplication, polynomials

Need help with my code, or any suggested codes that can solve the problem.

This is a photo of the desired program:

[image]

and here's my code:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It's ordered to do more than just the multiplication.

Comment: Please avoid posting images as text. You should copy/paste your code and format it properly using the tools available on the editor here

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.